# C# events struggle

Tags: c#, events

I was trying to write a simple code, which contains events whenever the train stops or drives
My application keeps crashing while saying that im trying to use a null Event.
Program Class:

```
public delegate void trainHandler();

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Train e = new Train();
        e.Boxcar += new trainHandler (Message);
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the train, next stop London!");
        string choice = "";
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("D-Drive\nS-Stop\nE-Exit ");
            choice = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            switch (choice)
            {
                case "D":
                    Train q = new Train();
                    q.Driving();
                    break;
                case "S":
                    Train q1 = new Train();
                    q1.Stopping();
                    break; 

            }
        } while (choice != "E");
    }
    static void Message()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thanks for riding our train!");
    }
}
```

New Class:

```
class Train
{
    public event trainHandler Boxcar;

    public void Driving()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The train took off!");
        if (Boxcar != null)
        {
            Boxcar(); 
        }

    }
    public void Stopping()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Train stoped, get down!");
        if (Boxcar != null)
        {
            Boxcar(); 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: In which line? Did you try to put a breakpoint and see ?

Comment: Yes, I did try but still coudnt figure it out.im trying to use the boxcar event in the stopping and driving methods, but it still shows up as a null event

Comment: Well you never actually call `Driving` or `Stopping` on the train object that you hooked the `Boxcar` event to `Message`.  On an aside you typically would assign `Boxcar` to a temp variable, check that for `null`, and then call the temp variable to make it thread safe, though that doesn't look like the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a *new* train in each of the case statements, neither of which have an event handler attached.  change your switch to trigger the event on th train that was created at the start of the program:

```
switch (choice)
{
    case "D":
        e.Driving();
        break;
    case "S":
        e.Stopping();
        break; 
}
```

Comment: Ohh! i didnt notice that! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `Train e = new Train();` where you assign the event to a handler, is a different `Train` instance to the ones on which you call `Drive` or `Stopping`

If you want your event to be called, you need to either call `Drive` or `Stopping` on your `e` instance, or assign an event handler to your new instances you create inside your `switch`

Comment: Thank you!! i didnt notice that, appreaciate it!